# How to fetch row count of related entities?

Tags: symfony, count, doctrine, one-to-many

I have two entities, `Class` and `Student`. One `Class` can have multiple `Student`s (oneToMany):

```
# YAML notation for Entity 'Class'
...
oneToMany:
    students:
        targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\Student
        mappedBy: class
```

For fetching all `Class`es, I'm writing my own query like this:

```
SELECT c
FROM MyBundle:Class c
WHERE c.whatever = :parameter
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

Now I'm trying to fetch a list of `Class`es, ordered (DESC) by the count of related `Student`s. So that the result would look like:

```
Class.id   Class.count(Student)
--------   --------------------
       3                    109
       1                     81
       4                     58
       2                     21
```

How would I go there? I tried something somewhat like this:

```
SELECT
    c,
    COUNT(c.students) AS students
FROM MyBundle:Class c
WHERE c.whatever = :param
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY students DESC
```

(Note: I implement [DoctrineExtensions' Date](https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions) function)

But I'm getting an error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 26 near 'students)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Comment: Try to add `GROUP BY c.id` to your query.

Comment: I did, still the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this in your `Class` repository:

```php
public function getAllClassesOrderedByNumberOfStudents()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('class');

    $buffer = $qb
        ->select('class, COUNT(students) AS students_per_class')
        ->innerJoin('class.students', 'students')
        ->groupBy('class.id')
        ->orderBy('students_per_class', 'DESC');

    $q = $buffer->getQuery();

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for accepting this late, somehow disappeared from my sight. Thanks!